# Cassandra not utilizing CPU and RAM

Tags: cassandra

We are running a Cassandra 5 nodes cluster (3.10) with 8 cores, 32 memory and 2TB disk each.
The cluster is running in k8s over google cloud.

Recently our disk size was increased from 400GB to ~ 800GB in each node, at that point we start suppering from many read/write timeouts.
when checking the usage of the node in their resources we notice that their CPU is at 1.5 - 2, ram is 17GB.

it seems like they are bound from some reason and the only observation we saw is that there a reverse correlation between disk size and used cpu, the higher disk usage the lower the cpu usage.

is there a way to see what's blocking the CPU and RAM from utilizing 100% of their resources?

Comment: have you check, how much Java Heap was given to Cassandra's JVM?

Comment: Read timeouts can typically be caused by a handful of issues (wide partitions, large result-sets, tombstones, network latencies, etc.). Many times you can see the queries issues in the cassandra logs. Now, write timeouts are more interesting, in my opinion. there typically isn't as many reasons. You could have I/O latencies and  network latencies. What are the client CL settings? Are you writing large batches? One thing in common to both are GCs. If you're having large GC wait times, that could impact everything. I would check your cassandra logs. Check iostat output, network latencies, etc.

Comment: When you say "disk size was increased". Are you saying you added storage, or you're consuming that additional storage? Adding storage should not have any impact on reads and/or writes. If you have the queries timing out, run them yourself with tracing enabled. That may help. I would first ensure GC is working properly.

Comment: Timeouts can be caused by many non-cpu/ram related things. Identifying what is timing out (slow query logger in client or C* good options), then why is it timing out (gcs, wide partitions, tombstones etc - depends on queries timing out) should be process.